# 405 Method not allowed when uploading file

Tags: angularjs, django, post, file-upload, http-status-code-405

I have a class-based view with a defined `post` method, which is the end-point of a file upload.

The request is made using the `ng-file-upload` module.

When executing the upload request, I receive a `405 Method not allowed` error.

If I try to make a POST to that same URL with the same parameters (except for the file), it's working fine.

I can see in Firebug that the Response Headers are different:

- When sending the request via POST, the response's allowed method are POST and OPTIONS
- When sending via upload, they are GET, HEAD and OPTIONS

What could be causing this?

[edit]
As requested, here is the (simplified) code of the view handling method:

```
def order_data(order, request):
    """
    Return a serialized order with added permission information
    """
    data = OrderSerializer(order).data

    # Add a few custom fields on the data dict

    return data

class SaveOrder(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data.get('order')

        if data.get('id', None) is not None:
            if not request.user.has_perm('orders.modify_order'):
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
            else:
                order = Order.objects.get(id=data['id'])
        else:
            if not request.user.has_perm('orders.create_order'):
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
            else:
                order = Order()

        # Fill in order using the fields in data

         order.save()

        return JsonResponse(order_data(order, request))
```

[edit2] Actually the behaviour is not exactly what I've described earlier:

- With `upload` to url `/order/save-order` I get an error saying that I need a trailing slash
- With `upload` to url `/order/save-order/` I get a 405
- With `post` to url `/order/save-order` it's working fine (original code)
- With `post` to url `/order/save-order/` I get a 404

Comment: Can you post the code for the view function/class that is handling this request?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my requests were actually done to 2 different urls, hence the upload failing.